# destroy box2d body in cocos2d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

I have a web and some insects i am throwing web and having collision detection with insects and destroying them. i have used bod2d for collision detection.

World Method

```
-(void)createWorld
{

 // Define the gravity vector.
    b2Vec2 b_gravity;
    b_gravity.Set(0.0f, -9.8f);

 // Do we want to let bodies sleep?
 // This will speed up the physics simulation
    bool doSleep = true;

 // Construct a world object, which will hold and simulate the rigid bodies.
    world = new b2World(b_gravity);
    world->SetAllowSleeping(doSleep);

    world->SetContinuousPhysics(true);

}
```

Create Web

```
-(void) createWeb
{
    freeBodySprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"web1.png"];
        [self addChild:freeBodySprite z:2 tag:TAG_WEB];

    CGPoint startPos = CGPointMake(100, 320/1.25);

    bodyDef.type = b2_staticBody;
    bodyDef.position = [self toMeters:startPos];
    bodyDef.userData = freeBodySprite;

    float radiusInMeters = ((freeBodySprite.contentSize.width * freeBodySprite.scale/PTM_RATIO) * 1.0f);
    shape.m_radius = radiusInMeters;

    fixtureDef.shape = &shape;
    fixtureDef.density = 0.01f;
    fixtureDef.friction = 0.1f;
    fixtureDef.restitution = 0.1f;

    circularObstacleBody = world->CreateBody(&bodyDef);
    stoneFixture = circularObstacleBody->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef);
        freeBody = circularObstacleBody;
}
```

I have created my insect animation with spritesheet and then created b2body for that Sprite

```
-(b2Body *) createMovingBoxObstacle
{


    //set this to avoid updating this object in the tick schedule
        _ants.userData = (void *)YES;

    b2BodyDef bodyDef_Ant;
    bodyDef_Ant.type = b2_dynamicBody;
    CGPoint startPos = ccp(520,winSize.height/7.6);
    bodyDef_Ant.position = [self toMeters:startPos];
    bodyDef_Ant.userData = _ants;

    b2PolygonShape dynamicBox;
    float tileWidth = ((_ants.contentSize.width * _ants.scale/PTM_RATIO) * 0.5f);
    float tileHeight = ((_ants.contentSize.height * _ants.scale/PTM_RATIO) * 0.5f);
    dynamicBox.SetAsBox(tileWidth, tileHeight);

    b2FixtureDef fixtureDef_Ant;
    fixtureDef_Ant.shape = &dynamicBox;
    fixtureDef_Ant.friction = 0.7;
    fixtureDef_Ant.density = 0.1f;
    fixtureDef_Ant.restitution = 0.7;


    staticBody = world->CreateBody(&bodyDef_Ant);
    staticBody->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef_Ant);

       VAMovingObstacle* moveableObject = [[VAMovingObstacle alloc] init];
       moveableObject.startPoint = ccp(520,winSize.height/7.6);
       moveableObject.endPoint = ccp(-50,winSize.height/7.6);
       moveableObject.transitionTime = 20.0;
       moveableObject.breakTime = 1.0;

    moveableObject.obstacleSprite = _ants;
    moveableObject.physicalBody = staticBody;
    [moveableObject startMovement];

    if (!movingObstacles) {
        movingObstacles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    [movingObstacles addObject:moveableObject];
    [moveableObject release];
    return staticBody;
}
```

VAMovingObstacle is a class which helps sprite along with b2body to move from left to right (runaction)

Here is my contact listner EndContact method

```
void ContactListener::EndContact(b2Contact* contact)
{
    b2Body* bodyA = contact->GetFixtureA()->GetBody();
    b2Body* bodyB = contact->GetFixtureB()->GetBody();

    if (bodyA->GetUserData() != NULL && bodyB->GetUserData() != NULL) {
        CCSprite *spriteA = (CCSprite *) bodyA->GetUserData();
        CCSprite *spriteB = (CCSprite *) bodyB->GetUserData();


        if (spriteA.tag == TAG_WEB && spriteB.tag >= TAG_ANT) {

        }

        else if (spriteA.tag >= TAG_ANT && spriteB.tag == TAG_WEB) {

            [spriteA removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
            [[HelloWorldLayer sharedLevel] WebCollisionWithInsect:bodyA];
        }
    }
}
```

when ever collision happens EndContact method calls WebCollisionWithInsect:bodyA

```
-(void) WebCollisionWithInsect:(b2Body*) bodyT{
            world->DestroyBody(bodyT);
}
```

On world->DestroyBody(bodyT) line it give an error

> Assertion failed: (IsLocked() == false), function DestroyBody, file
>   /Users/libs/Box2D/Dynamics/b2World.cpp, line 134.

Any Idea what i am doing wrong. ?

**Edited**
I have added this line in EndContact

```
destroyCollisionDetectionBody = objBody;
didInsectCollideWithWeb = YES;
```

Keeping reference of body i want to destroy. 
Now i can destroy my body inside tick method on if check 
Added these lines in tick method

```
if(didInsectCollideWithWeb)
    {
        [self unschedule:@selector(tick:)];
        [freeBodySprite removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES]; // this is my web
        world->DestroyBody(destroyCollisionDetectionBody);
        world->DestroyBody(freeBody);
        [self createWeb];
        [self schedule:@selector(tick:)];
        didInsectCollideWithWeb = NO;

    }
```

But now problem is that when i am destroying my web i.e freebody. i cant recreate it. as i was doing it before by calling [self createWeb];

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to destroy a `box2d` object while its being used in the simulation phase (as `EndContact` is called during that phase). The simulation phase is the one executed when you call the world's `step` method.

So what you should do is keep a reference to the body object you want to remove and after the box2d simulation phase (after the `step` method returns) execute the `WebCollisionWithInsect` with the desired body

Comment: Ok. but one more thing how will i know when the step method returns?

Comment: at some point in your code you have probably have b2world->Step(x,y);. This is the method that performs the physics simulation. So just after it you can remove the desired object(s)

Comment: i have destroyed my body but there is another problem see edited section please

Comment: @Zohaib What is exactly the problem with recreating the web ? does it crash ?

Comment: No it does not crash.. its not creating another web body when previous body is destroyed.